# Compare contents of 2 folders and remove files with the same name that are present in both folders

Tags: ruby, filesystems

I am currently writing a quick script in Ruby that goes through all the contents of two folders, and returns a list of all the files that are not in either of the two folders.
Currently what I am doing is storing the paths of all the files of each directory in an array:

```
Find.find(dir1) do |path|
  if File.file?(path)
    directory1_files << path # Add path to an array of file_paths for the 1st directory.
  end
end # I repeat the process for the second directory and store their paths in an array called directory2_files.
```

The problem I am having is that when I try and subtract the two arrays (larger array - small array)  to get the remaining files, I get an empty array. Reason I get this is because the full paths are trying to be subtracted instead of just the basenames. Ex: ~/folder1/file.txt != ~/folder2/file.txt 
How can I find if a file with the same name is in two folders, and remove it from a list so the only files remaining are the ones not present in both folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the paths to both folders (i.e. `dir1` and `dir2`) I'd suggest to to calculate paths relative to them, so that later you could compare relative paths (effectively ignoring the `~/folder1` part of the path). Use dictionaries to map between relative and absolute paths (so that you could remove them).

Something like this:

```
dir1 = '~/folder1'
directory1_files = {}

Find.find(dir1) do |path|
  if File.file?(path)
    relative_path = path[dir1.length, path.length]
    directory1_files[relative_path] = path
  end
end
```

Then, whenever you have `directory1_files` and `directory2_files`, compare their `.keys` in order to find the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Use File.basename(filename). This also works if "filename" is a File object.

Comment: This won't work with nested directories, i.e. `~dir1/file.txt` and `~dir2/subdir1/file.txt` will be considered having the same relative path, while they are do not.

Comment: The path is ignored with File.basename(). It returns only the file name without its directory part. 
Both File.basename('~/dir1/file.txt') and File.basename('~/dir2/subdir1/file.txt') return 'file.txt'.